# CSS - All :hover event elements should be #fff text color

Tags: html, css, hover

I've got some problems with block's child elements on `:hover` event. I've a pricing block and the main task is to get all texts **#fff** color on `:hover`.

Because when I'am trying to `:hover` `<h3>` element and `<p>` element they are `:hover` well, but I need it change their colors even when I just `:hover` the parent block. 
               But how can I do this without JavaScript? Is it possible or I something missed?

**This is my HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div id="Pricing">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Pricing Plans</h1>
            <div class="price-group">
                <div class="price-block">
                    <h3>Students</h3>
                    <span class="price-main">$ 8</span>
                    <span class="price-additional">Per Month</span>
                    <p class="footnote">Personal License</p>
                    <button class="btn-price">Purchase</button>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**And CSS:**

```
.price-block {
    width: 270px;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.price-block:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.price-block h3 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Here is some pics:**
[image]
[image]

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a cascading style, for all child elements. `*` applies to all children (and their children). To avoid styling the text of the button you should use `:not(button)`, which will keep the button text black as in your image.

**This is the styling rule you should add:**

```
.price-block:hover *:not(button) {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Demonstration:

```css
.price-block {
    width: 270px;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.price-block:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.price-block:hover *:not(button) {
  color: #fff;
}

.price-block h3 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="Pricing">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Pricing Plans</h1>
            <div class="price-group">
                <div class="price-block">
                    <h3>Students</h3>
                    <span class="price-main">$ 8</span>
                    <span class="price-additional">Per Month</span>
                    <p class="footnote">Personal License</p>
                    <button class="btn-price">Purchase</button>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add adjust the css style as shown below.

```
.price-block {
    width: 270px;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.price-block:hover *:not('.btn-price') {
    color: #fff;
}

.price-block:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.price-block h3 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all child with *;

```css
.price-block:hover *{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```